# How to match the same pattern in a string(one line) and perform the same action again

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics

suppose `$dna = "aaaaccccttttaaaaggggaaaacccccaaaaggggaaaacccctttttttt"`

I want to cut between each aaaa & cccc in thee string
and put on new line. For example, I want to get

```
aaaa
ccccttttaaaaggggaaaa
cccccaaaaggggaaaa
cccctttttttt
```

my code:

```
 if ($DNA =~ /(.*)$match(.*)/) { # $match would be aaaacccc together
               my $fragment1 = $1.$pre-match; # pre-match is aaaa
               my $fragment2 = $post-match.$2; # post-match is cccc
               print"$fragment1\n$fragment2\n";
```

I want to cut on every match.

**Very Important, dna CANNOT be cut if only post-match. There must be a pre-match**

Let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
$dna = "aaaaccccttttaaaaggggaaaacccccaaaaggggaaaacccctttttttt";
$dna =~ s/(.*?)(cccc.*?)/$1\n$2/g;

print "$dna\n";
```

The regex will add a newline before every `cccc`

Outputs:

```
aaaa
ccccttttaaaaggggaaaa
cccccaaaaggggaaaa
cccctttttttt
```

Comment: I'd suggest the `/r` flag as an non-destructive solution as well. `say $dna =~ s/(.+?)(cccc.+?)/$1\n$2/gr;`, only works in more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to split the string and join it with `"\n"`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.01;

my $dna = "aaaaccccttttaaaaggggaaaacccccaaaaggggaaaacccctttttttt";
my ($split_left, $split_right) = ('aaaa','cccc');

say join "\n", split /(?<=$split_left)(?=$split_right)/, $dna;
```

Post match and pre match are predefined terms in perl and mean the whole string before and after the last match (you can access them with the `/p` flag via `${^PREMATCH}` and `${^POSTMATCH}`). Also variable names in perl can't contain `-` since it is an operator, use `_` or camelCasing instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplist way is to add line breaks with a substitution:

```
$dna =~ s/aaaacccc/aaaa\ncccc/g;
```